# Why did "inter-racial" marriage attract disapproval even from African-Americans?

Tags: united-states, racism, marriage

In a post by Gallup, [In U.S., 87% Approve of Black-White Marriage, vs. 4% in 1958](http://www.gallup.com/poll/163697/approve-marriage-blacks-whites.aspx), past polls indicate that while the majority of African-Americans have approved of "inter-racial" marriages since polling began, there was only 56% approval amongst African-Americans in 1969. (It's now up to 96%)

Why did "inter-racial" marriages attract significant disapproval even from African-Americans?

Comment: I couldn't really mention it in the question, but I want to credit http://xkcd.com/1431/ for indicating that majority approval of the United States as a whole for racial marriage happened in 1995.

Comment: Is bigotry a whites-only phenomenon? I imagine they disapproved for the same reason whites did: mistrust of people who are different from themselves.

Comment: It's not just African-Americans.  I'm white, married to a Chinese--and she's gotten flak several times from other Chinese people for marrying outside her race.

Comment: Whilst the common answer is that it's simple racism, I think it has more to do with the dilution and possible extinction of the respective cultures.

Comment: Not obvious what kind of answer you are really looking for in this question.

Comment: This may simply be a a question of correcting unfounded assumptions.. @AndrewGrimm it may help if you provide explanation of why you expect these numbers to be different for African-Americans then for the general population.

Comment: "since polling began, there was only 56% approval amongst African-Americans in 1969. (It's now up to 96%). Isn't there a contradiction between your question and understanding, as there is only 4% disapproval now?

Comment: It  might be interesting to compare attitudes by gender. If one gender perceives their prospects out of their race are worse than the other that could result in resentment.

Comment: You might want to read up on [black separatism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_separatism); I'm not sure how much of this is politics rather than something else.

Answer (score 12):

Race.
Bigotry is not prevalent in only one race. It exists in members of all races. The same goes for marriage and bigotry. Certain people believe in only marrying members of one's own race.
In the 1960's though, there was a larger racial divide and a lot more bigotry prevalent. Which meant a lot more separation of races.  You would be percieved badly if you were to marry outside your race in the 60's.
It is a lot more common to see interracial couples these days and a lot more tolerance and love for humans no matter what skin color they are. So bigotry has slid greatly since the 70s, but its still very much alive.